# JUnit: share resource between test classes that uses same extension

Tags: kotlin, testing, junit, junit5

**My case**: in my personal kotlin project I use JUnit 5 for testing. And I have three test groups: unit tests, integration tests and end-to-end tests.
Unit tests works fine as they don't require anything. Integration tests require database connection, and end-to-end tests require whole application context.

**Implementation**: All integration tests classes annotated with `@ExtendsWith(DatabaseTestExt::class)`. `DatabaseTestExt` implements `BeforeEachCallback` (cleanup database before each test) and `BeforeAllCallback`. In this callback I instanciate and put once resource that implements `ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource` (because I have to close database connection and stop DI context before end of tests execution). Similar logic for end-to-end tests: start logging, start DI, launch web application.

Here's the short version of extension class. Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/kam1sh/ar2/blob/ddff0406d18b5d7797fd5d5354d9b0dc7f792928/src/test/kotlin/ar2/tests/integration/database/DatabaseTestExt.kt#L15).

```kotlin
class DatabaseTestExt : BeforeAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback, KoinComponent {

    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext) {
        context.getStore(ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL).getOrComputeIfAbsent("db") {
            CloseableDatabase()
        }
    }

    class CloseableDatabase : ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {
        init {
            // initialize logging, DI and database logic
        }

        override fun close() {
            // stop DI and database
        }
    }

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        // clean up database
    }
}
```

**The problem**: With such implementation JUnit creates and closes database resource in each test class. I want it to share resource between all tests annotated with `@ExtendsWith(DatabaseTestExt::class)`, because ORM instantiation is not cheap it terms of time.

I thought about using `context.root.getStore()` instead of `context.getStore()`, but then it looks like context lifecycle ends in the end of the whole test suite, and this is not good for my case because DI initialization from `DatabaseTestExt` conflicts with `EndToEndTestExt`.

So, is it possible to share resource between test classes that uses same JUnit extension in JUnit 5? If not, can you suggest some testing frameworks that supports such logic?

Thank you.

P.S.: I thought about posting this on sqa.stackexchange.com, but decided to post it here at first.

**UPD: I found a workaround for my specific case**:

- initialize database connection with ORM on first `beforeAll()` call and put those resources in **root** context store.
- on each `beforeAll()` call in extension start DI (it's cheap), extract from store saved previously connection, and put it in DI.
- on each `afterAll()` call in extension destroy DI context, but don't touch database connection.

This way, I achieve sharing resource between multiple test classes. However, the problem from title remains unanswered =/

Comment: found any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can use `TestContainers` and put the docker of your DB into it.

`TestContainers` has good integration with `JUnit5`.

There is an example of usage `Shared` container
https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/#shared-containers

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes, I know about TestContainers. But the problem is not in database, it's in sharing some resource between group of tests. In my case it's Hibernate's SessionFactory: it instantiates slowly, so I want to share its instance between only and only database tests. This is my problem.